# View last time an app was opened

Tags: macos, applications

I'm new to Mac and I want to know the last time I opened an app on my Mac and what the app was. Like for example if I opened Sublime Text at 2:04 pm how would I see that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open /Applications in Finder in list view and show the Last Opened column by right-clicking the column titles and adding the column. This will show the last time an app was opened, and sorting by that column will order by most recently used.